# Unable to install ubuntu 18.04.3 using bootable USB

Tags: boot, usb

I have created custom ISO using systemback application.Later same ISO is converted to bootable USB via Rufus.While converting bootable USB,Rufus has selected NTFS file system due to larger size of ISO(is about 4.7GB).I'm able to boot ubuntu from the same USB, but unable to install same system(the one which USB has).While installing,following error is occurred "systemback live image could not be mounted"

Please help me,if anyone has ever encountered such situation.

Comment: I have not always had good luck with NTFS for Live or Persistent USBs. Have you tried Startup Disk Creator or mkusb, These use ISO9660 which might help.

Comment: "I have created custom ISO": there is probably an issue with your custom ISO or the method you used to prepare it.  Please try an official ISO image and report back if you have the same issue.  Otherwise, if your question is pertaining to how to create a custom ISO -- [this method](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48535/how-to-customize-the-ubuntu-live-cd/49679#49679) still works.  Rufus is also not the best method out there to write, since it gives options that won't work -- like formatting the drive as NTFS (it should be FAT) - try Etcher or Startup Disk Creator

Comment: @ C.S.Cameron, I have also used startup disk creator to convert bootable USB from custom ISO,that never worked.So went with Rufus way.

Comment: @ Nmath, I have another ISO which has been generated through systemback and it's size is 4GB. By using Rufus I converted it to bootable USB.That's working fine,in the sense I'm able to install the same.Problem is when ISO is >4GB.